# Debian Jessie 8.3 can't close windows with touchscreen

Tags: debian, multi-touch, hid, touchscreen, debian-jessie

I've got a problem with Debian Jessie (8.3 with XFCE) and can't use any one else.
Touch screen works almost correctly ( cursor fallows finger, select new window when click on it ) but can't access to windows icons placed on menu bar (on right top: open, minimize maximize etc...). Nothing happen whenI click on it.

I recompiled hid_multitouch drivers with last version of jessie and issue is not resolved.

This is some information about the touchscreen device:

> lsusb:
> Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0c45:8420 Microdia

.

> dmesg on connexion
>
> plug:
>
> Jan  2 20:58:44 superviseur kernel: [  220.800029] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
>
> Jan  2 20:58:44 superviseur kernel: [  220.967152] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=8420
>
> Jan  2 20:58:44 superviseur kernel: [  220.967160] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
>
> Jan  2 20:58:44 superviseur kernel: [  220.967166] usb 3-2: Product: XINMO0touch
>
> Jan  2 20:58:44 superviseur kernel: [  220.967170] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ONEZZDGGlectronics
>
> Jan  2 20:58:44 superviseur kernel: [  221.018401] input: ONEZZDGGlectronics XINMO0touch as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:0C45:8420.0003/input/input9
>
> Jan  2 20:58:44 superviseur kernel: [  221.019224] hid-multitouch 0003:0C45:8420.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.12 Mouse [ONEZZDGGlectronics XINMO0touch] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-2/input0
>
> unplug:
>
> Jan  2 21:00:44 superviseur kernel: [  340.900140] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 3

This issue doesn't occurs on Debian 9.
If somebody have an idea and can help it should be really appraciate.

Many Thanks in advance

Superbebert
[image: Can't close windows touchscreen Debian 8.3]

Answer (score 0):

After a long fight with  everythings ( computer, electricity, USB drivers, kernel, dogs cats and my mother and low) ... I Found ...

I used twofing driver, downloadable  [here](http://plippo.de/p/twofing)

Simple and funny.

Many thanks to Philipp Merkel.